# Using sudo in Git Extensions when pushing changes to remote Linux repo

Tags: git, sudo

I have Git Extensions v3.1.1 installed in Windows 7 Pro.

Rephrased my problem description:
Remote GIT repo is Debian Linux, I connect to it with myuser which has sudo permission.
The /etc directory is on this remote Linux system, having root:root owner.
Local GIT repo is on Windows 7 Pro, where the Git Extensions is installed.

I don't get root permission for the remote Linux server, just sudo for myuser. But myuser is not allowed to modify /etc directory content of remote Linux repo, because /etc directory is owned by root:root. My problem is with pushing the changes to the remote Linux repo.

I would need to use sudo because the etckeeper installed on remote Linux needs root or sudo for /etc directory (which is owned by root).

If I connect remote Linux repo with myuser, pushing the changes to /etc is denied because the /etc owner is root:root.

How can I push changes to /etc as root, while I was connected to remote Linux repo as myuser (which has sudo permission added)?

Comment: Do you actually have /etc on Windows 7?

Comment: No. Remote repo is on Debian Linux. The /etc directory is on this system. Local repo is on Windows 7 Pro, the Git Extensions, too.

Comment: Rephrased the OP

Comment: So I guess you're using etckeeper. You wouldn't use its repository as a remote, not directly anyway. Instead, you can use a common remote repository for both `/etc` and your local clone.